# data transfering problem WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

Why cant I send array with more than 3000 elements with size ~5 MB but with table with size 2500 elements there is no problem ?

```
<binding name="testBinding" maxBufferSize="100485760" maxReceivedMessageSize="100485760" maxBufferPoolSize="100485760" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000" maxStringContentLength="100485760" maxArrayLength="100485760" maxBytesPerRead="100485760" maxNameTableCharCount="100485760" />
        </binding>
```

Changing of any of this parameters doesnt give any good results

Comment: what happens? also - is this maybe a firewall/network-device limit? and have you played with the timeouts? or just the quotas?

Comment: no firewall, yes I checked timeouts, it is on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hosting your service in IIS. In such case you must also set ASP.NET request limit which is by default 4096KB.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: doesnt work, the same problem, besides I think that maxRequest isnt the problme maybe maxResponse ? but I cant see that attribute

Comment: @gruber: So you should provide more information. You didn't mention how do you host the service, you didn't mention if it is client or server config, you didn't mention if you upload or download data etc.